# AOSP WifiSettings Access points list not updating

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments, android-source, android-wifi

I am working on the AOSP code pie version. I had done few changes and after my build, the Wifi Access points(available wifi networks) list is not updating automatically in the Wi-Fi Settings page until i come back and start that again. I have not done any changes in packages/apps/Settings/src/.../wifi/WifiSettings.java file.

I did some analysis by checking logs of the image before issue and image after issue. i found that one of the OverRidden method 'onAccessPointsChanged' is not called in issue build. can anyone help me understand why its happening and how I can go forward with this and resolve the issue?

Below is the log without issue:

```
2019-11-13 22:07:57.322 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/SettingsActivity: Switching to fragment com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings
2019-11-13 22:07:57.322 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/SubSettings: Launching fragment com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings
2019-11-13 22:07:57.329 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/Settings_WifiSettings: onCreate
2019-11-13 20:31:47.857 2439-2439/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 20:31:47.877 2439-2439/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 20:31:47.902 2439-2439/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointsChanged (WifiTracker) callback initiated
2019-11-13 20:31:57.860 2439-2439/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 20:31:57.875 2439-2439/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 20:31:57.903 2439-2439/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointsChanged (WifiTracker) callback initiated
```

Below is the log with issue:

```
2019-11-13 22:07:57.322 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/SettingsActivity: Switching to fragment com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings
2019-11-13 22:07:57.322 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/SubSettings: Launching fragment com.android.settings.wifi.WifiSettings
2019-11-13 22:07:57.329 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/Settings_WifiSettings: onCreate
2019-11-13 22:07:57.735 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 22:07:57.743 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 22:07:57.755 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
2019-11-13 22:07:57.758 5617-5617/com.android.settings D/WifiSettings: onAccessPointChanged (singular) callback initiated
```

Below is the link for the WifiSettings.java file from androidxref:
http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/packages/apps/Settings/src/com/android/settings/wifi/WifiSettings.java

Comment: git bisect from a working commit and HEAD until you found the one that broke the feature. It's kind of impossible to guess which of your change broke it.